# When is my C# property initialized?

Tags: c#, properties, initialization, getter

I'm a little confused about when exactly my Property is being initialized.

Suppose I have a property declared like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> MessageLookup
    {
        get
        {
           return messages ?? doSomething();
        }
    }
```

The doSomething method populates the messages Dictionary and returns it.

My question is, when is this code run?
If I place a breakpoint into the doSomething code, it isn't hit, but the MessageLookup property is holding data (this is the only place it is initialized) when I view it in the debugger.

Is this code run at construction? does the debugger run it automatically when I hover over the variable name? If so, why isn't the breakpoint hit?

Comment: Could you post a bit of the content of the doSomething method?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `return messages ?? doSomething()` without your project running, and then run it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is run whenever anyone refers to the property, and not before.

If you use the debugger, you'll see it because the debugger tries to fetch property values automatically (so you can see the state of the object). I don't know whether the debugger ignores breakpoints while it's evaluating properties for itself - that would explain everything.

Try running your code *not* in a debugger, and make some code access your property:

```
var lookup = someObject.MessageLookup;
```

Make `doSomething()` dump a stack trace and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting this...
The debugger will not hit breakpoints in doSomething if it does the automatic fetch?

Comment: The debugger ignores everything, including sanity, during func eval. http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2007/03/13/func-eval-abort-is-evil.aspx

Comment: @Me: I love func eval. I just make sure my pure methods (including the ones the debugger assumes are pure) behave themselves and it's never an issue.

Comment: Depending on the debugger, he could bypass some of these issues by using things like `DebuggerHidden` and other such attributes from the `System.Diagnostics` namespace (i.e. debugger will ignore and not automatically evaluate these properties), allowing him to still use the debugger and step into his code w/o having to do the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It is run when your property is first evaluated. No background stuff going on.

I'm guessing you're not seeing this because you use Quickwatch to inspect your object. At that point it will get executed and your breakpoint will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Property getters (and `ToString()` for that matter) are assumed to be [pure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute%28VS.100%29.aspx), which basically means evaluating it has no side effects. You should rewrite the code to adhere to that assumption or you'll face [nasty consequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/03/23/400794.aspx). If must use lazy initialization at access time, use a `GetMessageLookup()` method instead.